# Restrictions on stack use when defining words?

Tags: stack, forth, gforth

I was testing the use of [] inside a definition, I got an error:

```
: x [ here ] ;
:2: unstructured
: x [ here ] >>>;<<<
```

I understand that the cause of the error is having grown/decreased the stack while compiling. The culprit can be any "immediate" word:

```
: y + ; immediate  ok
1 2 y . 3  ok
4 5   ok
: x y ; 
:4: unstructured 
: x y >>>;<<<
```

My question is: is it part of the standard or just the gforth implementation?

Are there any other restrictions on the use of the stack?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is it part of the standard or just the gforth implementation?

It is a part of the standard.

The [word `:`](https://forth-standard.org/standard/core/Colon) leaves *colon-sys* on the data stack: `( -- colon-sys )`.
The [word `;`](https://forth-standard.org/standard/core/Semi) consumes *colon-sys* from the data stack: `( colon-sys -- )`.

*colon-sys* is a [system-compilation data type](https://forth-standard.org/standard/usage#subsubsection.3.1.5.1). The size of *colon-sys* is implementation dependent. It can occupy 0 cells in the data stack, or ten cells, or more.

The following line, when run with the empty data stack, will output the *colon-sys* tuple.

```
: x [ cr .s cr ] ;
```

In turn, the word `;` throws an exception if it does not encounter *colon-sys* at the top of the stack (for example, if you put something on the stack over *colon-sys*). Throwing exception in this case is not obligated, but [allowed by the standard](https://forth-standard.org/standard/usage#usage:data) due to an ambiguous condition.

Therefor, doing compilation of a definition, it's not easy to consume something from the data stack or leave something on the stack. You can use variables, or a user-defined stack, or, if creating a definition programmatically, the return stack.

---

Formally, *colon-sys* is placed on the [control-flow stack](https://forth-standard.org/standard/usage#subsubsection.3.2.3.2). But the control-flow stack may be implemented using the data stack. Anyway, the result is that *colon-sys* may occupy 0 or more data stack cells.